# List padding issue

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>My first styled page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
  body {
   background-image: url("http://technozed.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/firewatch-wallpaper-13.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-color: #black;
            background-size: cover;
            padding-left: 11em;
            font-family: Lucida Handwriting, Monotype Corsiva, Times, serif;
            color: white;
            background-color: black
        }
        #bg {
            z-index: -1;
        }
        ul {
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px black;
            background-color: #131b28;
            top: 0em;
            left: 0em;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 11%;
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        li a {
   margin: 0 0;
            display: block;
            color: #FF6C40;
            padding: 100%;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        li a.active {
            background-color: #2C112B;
            color: #FF6C40;
        }
        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            background-color: #2C112B;
            color: #FF6C40;
        }
  h1 {
   border-bottom: thin dotted;
   margin: 0 0;
   padding: 8px 0px;
  }
  address {
   border-top: thin dotted;
   margin 0px 0px;
   padding: 8px 0px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Site navigation menu -->
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Wildlife Sanctions</a></li>
        <li><a href="musings.html">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="town.html">Camping Sites</a></li>
        <li><a href="links.html">Donations</a></li></ul>
    
 <!-- Main content -->
    <h1>My first styled page</h1>
    <p>Welcome to my styled page!</p>
        <p>It lacks images, but at least it has style. And it has links, even if they don't go anywhere&hellip;</p>
            <p>There should be more here, but I don't know what yet.</p>
    
 <!-- Sign and date the page, it's only polite! -->
 <address>Made 5 April 2004<br> by myself.</address>
</body>

</html>
```

I've made a webpage but when I run the code, the *navbar* located at the left side of the screen, doesn't look quite right and the contents of it, instead of  covering the total area of the *navbar*. I made an effort to correct this mistake by adjusting the percentage of the padding of the `li a {}` part of the style sheet but when the code runs on a monitor of different aspect ratios, the problem returns again. How can I fix this?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url("http://technozed.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/firewatch-wallpaper-13.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-color: #black;
        background-size: cover;
        padding-left: 11em;
        font-family: Lucida Handwriting, Monotype Corsiva, Times, serif;
        color: white;
        background-color: black
    }
    #bg {
        z-index: -1;
    }
    ul {
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px black;
        background-color: #131b28;
        top: 0em;
        left: 0em;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 11%;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    li a {
        margin: 0 0;
        display: block;
        color: #FF6C40;
        padding: 100%;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a.active {
        background-color: #2C112B;
        color: #FF6C40;
    }
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #2C112B;
        color: #FF6C40;
    }
    h1 {
        border-bottom: thin dotted;
        margin: 0 0;
        padding: 8px 0px;
    }
    address {
        border-top: thin dotted;
        margin 0px 0px;
        padding: 8px 0px;
    }
</style>
```

And here is a "snippet" of my HTML code;

```
<body>
<!-- Site navigation menu -->
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html">Wildlife Sanctions</a></li>
    <li><a href="musings.html">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="town.html">Camping Sites</a></li>
    <li><a href="links.html">Donations</a></li></ul>
<!-- Main content -->
<h1>My first styled page</h1>
<p>Welcome to my styled page!</p>
    <p>It lacks images, but at least it has style. And it has links, even if they don't go anywhere&hellip;</p>
        <p>There should be more here, but I don't know what yet.</p>
            <!-- Sign and date the page, it's only polite! --><address>Made 5 April 2004<br> by myself.</address>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: @Shihab Please don't edit code in a question, especially when that code error may in fact be the problem the question is asking about.

Comment: I haven't edited the code, only shortened the paragraphs.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem... or why there is `padding-top: 100%` and `padding-bottom: 100%` on the anchors in the list, these would appear to cause issues if you didn't want the items spaced vertically over the entire area.

Answer (score 3):

your syntax for `ul` closing is wrong. Please update the last line.

```
    <li><a href="links.html">Donations</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: Done, but it hasn't changed anything. The problem still persists.

Comment: @TheKetch Can you show the actual demo on plunker or any demo link ?